# Django model changes cannot be migrated after a Git pull

Tags: python, django, git

I am working on a Django project with another developer. I had initially created a model which I had migrated and was synced correctly with a MySQL database.

The other developer had later pulled the code I had written so far from the repository and added some additional fields to my model.

When I pulled through his changes to my local machine the model had his changes, and additionly a second migration file had been pulled.

So I then executed the migration commands:
`python manage.py makemigrations myapp`, then `python manage.py migrate` in order to update my database schema. The response was that no changes had been made.

I tried removing the migration folder in my app and running the commands again. A new migrations folder had been generated and again my database schema had not been updated.

Is there something I am missing here? I thought that any changes to model can simply be migrated to alter the database schema.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (Using Django version 1.9).

Comment: If you could give some idea about what the model changes are and what hte migrations look like it would be great. Also please don't delete the migrations folder and createa  new one, it will cause problems for every other dev in the project.

Comment: If the other developer had already created migrations, there shouldn't be any need for you to do the same; you just need to run the ones they created.

Answer (score 0):

After you pull, do not delete the migrations file or folder. Simply just do `python manage.py migrate`. Even after this there is no change in database schema then open the migrations file which came through the git pull and remove the migration code of the model whose table is not being created in the database. Then do  makemigrations and migrate. I had this same problem. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your ProcFile add this line at the beginning.

```
release: python manage.py migrate
```